# Wordpress error 404 to access custom subfolder in current template foler

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My wordpress blog is installed in a subfoler : /wp/. I have create a subfolder in in the directory of the theme used : /test/

But when I try to access by the url : http//www.domain.com/wp/test/. I have an error 404

My .htaccess in wordpress root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My .htaccess in \test\ folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the `RewriteBase` to `RewriteBase /wp/test/` and the last rule to `RewriteRule . /wp/test/index [L]`

Comment: on the first or second .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

ry replacing your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^test(/|$) - [L,NC]
```